# Would condo HOA insurance cover damage to guest vehicles?

Tags: insurance, rental-property, home-owners-association

I recently stayed in an airbnb; it was a unit in a condo complex with a shared parking lot and an HOA. I drove my Tesla there, and plugged it into an outdoor outlet on the side of a covered parking structure (I parked next to said structure) at around 7 PM.

Sometime after ~10 PM and before 5 AM, the charging cable was somehow unplugged from adapter that goes into the wall, leaving only the 115v adapter plugged into the wall, while the rest of the charging cable ended up in the middle of the driveable area of the parking lot: See [Sentry Mode clip](https://youtu.be/FRSOiaXNv3I?t=40). In that clip, the charging cable had formerly been plugged into that structure on the right, above and to the right of that little loop thing that's sticking out. Sentry mode failed to record any event of when or how the cable was unplugged. At 5 AM, this clip was recorded by my car's sentry mode cameras (Cameras that are always recording, and will save 10 minutes of footage if it detects someone or something lingering nearby).

As seen in the video, a snow plow runs over the charging cable and rips it forcibly out of my car's charge port. This completely destroys the charge port, rendering the car incapable of charging up until I can get it repaired. (The cable locks in place in the car unless I use a key to unlock it and remove the cable).

Only the 115v adapter was left in the wall; the charging cable is now missing. Then, at around 7 AM, a "Violation Notice" is put onto my car by the HOA with the description "Unauthorized use of HOA electricity - please run a drop cord to your unit." Upon calling the number indicated; the guy ONLY saw the adapter sticking out of the wall, not even connected to my car; but that was enough for him to give me the notice I guess. It was just a warning and there was no real consequence to this notice. He had no idea that there used to be a charge cable connected to the car or anything and said he'd ask around about that and get back to me. I tried calling him back later, left a voicemail, but never heard back from him again.

$1,040 and an emergency 160 mile (somewhat harrowing and range-anxiety-inducing) trip to a Tesla service center through the mountains later and my car is charging normally again.

So I guess my long-winded question is: Would the HOA's insurance policy cover this kind of damage to my vehicle? To this day I'm still extremely puzzled as to how my charging cable ended up in the middle of the street. I suspect a bear, my father suspects an EV/Tesla-hater; but neither of us really knows.

If it matters, it's quite clear the HOA is very aware most of the units are AirBnbs; there were signs indicating airbnb instructions/rules posted outside on the stairwells, etc. Also I did file a police report, and did not file w/ my car insurance (my car insurance deductible is $1,000 so it didn't seem worth it).

TLDR: Snow plow ran over Tesla charging cable, destroying the port on the car itself causing $1,040 worth of damage; Would the HOA's insurance that the airbnb is part of cover this damage? (Video: [here](https://youtu.be/FRSOiaXNv3I?t=40))

If there is a better StackExchange site to post this on let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this a legal question about if the damage should be covered by the car owner's, unit owner's or HOA insurance policy. Or maybe none of them. Check with law.stackexchange.com

Comment: Why the HOA, and not the company/operator managing the snow plow? (This could be the same entity: the HOA may be contracting for snow removal.)

Comment: This question is not off-topic, it is the type of question insurance agents frequently handle. The damage is covered by the snow plow's commercial auto insurance coverage, not the condo insurance (the snow plow is almost certainly a subcontractor with an indemnification agreement in the plowing contract). Ask the owner of the Airbnb to get you the contact information for the snow plow company.

Answer (score 1):

HOA's are extremely stringent. Having said that, it's very unlikely they will pay for any damage related to your, or any, vehicle. It can boil down to the HOA Board, so it's hard to assume what they will agree on, but I can assure you, based on experience, that it's very unlikely they'll pay out on this claim. I don't mean to be a downer, I just wanted to be straight with you. But you can give it a shot, and it'd probably be worth a small amount of your time, but once you start seeing that you're being jerked around, I'd just retreat. If their counsel needs to get involved, they'll fight tooth and nail to not pay out. The onus will be on you/the owner of the unit to be more responsible and run the cord to the unit. Their take will be that you've violated their code, regardless of the damage to your vehicle.

Hope it all works out and sorry about your situation.